# Expanding a Nested Class in derived class C#

Tags: c#, oop

I want to have a base class with a nested class inside it - and expand the nested class in the child class:
From some reason - I can't access the Nested Derived Class NEW (added) properties:

```
public class BaseClass
{
    public NestedClass nestedClass {get; set;}
    public BaseClass()
    {
       nestedClass = new NestedClass();
    }
    public int baseproperty {get; set;}
    public  class NestedClass
    {
        public int NestedProperty {get; set;}
    }
}

public class Derived : BaseClass
{
    public class NestedClass
    {
          public DeeperNestedClass deeper {get; set;}
          public NestedClass()
          {
              deeper = new DeeperNestedClass();
          }
          public class DeeperNestedClass
          {
               public int VeryDeepPropery {get; set;}
          }


    }
}

Derived MyDerived = new Derived();
MyDerived.nestedClass.deeper   <----- Doesn't recognized !
```

*** edit - fixed the missing "class" in base class

Comment: why do you want to use `partial` here?

Comment: In this code `BaseClass.NestedClass` is not related to `Derived.NestedClass`. They would be cosnidered as two different classes.

Comment: @user54321 you are correct as B.K. I removed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You basically have three problems:

1) You actually have to derive `Derived.NestedClass` from `BaseClass.NestedClass`.

2) Your property `BaseClass.nestedClass` will always have the type of `BaseClass.NestedClass` so you need to cast it to access the `deeper` property.

3) You have to make sure that the property `BaseClass.nestedClass` actually hold an object of the type `Derived.NestedClass` when accessed in `Derived`.

```
public class BaseClass {
   public NestedClass nestedClass { get; set; }

   public BaseClass() {
      nestedClass = new NestedClass();
   }

   public int baseproperty { get; set; }

   public class NestedClass {
      public int NestedProperty { get; set; }
   }
}

public class Derived : BaseClass {
   public Derived() {
      nestedClass = new NestedClass();
   }

   public class NestedClass : BaseClass.NestedClass {
      public DeeperNestedClass deeper { get; set; }

      public NestedClass() {
         deeper = new DeeperNestedClass();
      }

      public class DeeperNestedClass {
         public int VeryDeepPropery { get; set; }
      }
   }
}

class Program {
   static void Main(string[] args) {
      Derived derived = new Derived();
      BaseClass.NestedClass nestedBase = derived.nestedClass;
      Derived.NestedClass nestedDerived = (Derived.NestedClass)nestedBase;
      Derived.NestedClass.DeeperNestedClass deeper = nestedDerived.deeper;
      int property = deeper.VeryDeepPropery;
   }
}
```

---

Edit after the discussion in the comments:
Maybe something simple like this will work for you?

```
public class OuterClass {
   public OuterClass() {
      nestedClass = new NestedClass();
   }

   public int baseproperty { get; set; }
   public NestedClass nestedClass { get; set; }
}

public class NestedClass {
   public NestedClass() {
      deeper = new DeeperNestedClass();
   }
   public int NestedProperty { get; set; }
   public DeeperNestedClass deeper { get; set; }
}

public class DeeperNestedClass {
   public int VeryDeepPropery { get; set; }
}

class Program {
   static void Main(string[] args) {
      OuterClass outer = new OuterClass();
      int property = outer.nestedClass.deeper.VeryDeepPropery;
   }
}
```

Comment: It's pretty cool that you got it to work... but that's note the sort of code I'd want to deal with.

Comment: @B.K. That's true! I'd never write such code in a production application.

Comment: This is a c# class that should be matched to a JSON scheme from external source. I can't change the JSON, so I'm forced to use this kind of structure. but the question is about OOP - expanding a derived nested class... I'm checking if this solution works

Comment: @Dani What about interfaces?

Comment: make the base class an interface ? some of the properties on the base nested class are "real" properties, the derived nested class adds to that some more. I am not sure it suits for Interface..

Comment: @Dani Why do you need nested classes to deserialize some JSON? Just because the data is nested in JSON doesn't mean you can't use simple classes.

Comment: I'm  trying to Access derived.nested.deeper but I can't see it, I see only the properties of the nested class from BASE.....

Comment: @Dani Please check my edited alternative solution. If I understand your JSON requirements correctly that should work.

Comment: Testing it now. Will update soon, thanks ! (the original solution seems to work as well, but it's an ugly code: ((Derived.Nested)dervice.nested).deeper.verydeeperproperty = 3. it's ugly...

Comment: I've moved the nested classes outside and it looks like JSON is the same which is good.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you have to specify that `NestedClass` is a `class` and `partial` during its declaration:

```
public partial class NestedClass  // You forgot those two here...
{
    public int NestedProperty { get; set; }
}
```

Furthermore, you cannot split the nested class into two separate classes, even if one of them derives from the other.  You may only do in the original base class if you split it and mark it as partial: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wa80x488(v=vs.120).aspx

Well.. at least not in a sane way.  `cremor` seems to have figured out a work-around, but I would steer clear of that kind of code.

Comment: Thanks, I actually had it on my code. missed it here, so it doesn't solve the problem, I will fix it in the question description

Comment: @Dani I provided a link for you to read over.  It's from MSDN and it goes into how you may split the nested class... however, you won't be able to accomplish it by splitting it into a derived class.

Comment: You are correct - Partial is not suitable here. I removed it. thanks for the article link

Answer (score 2):

You can't have partial classes nested in different classes.

Otherwise, what would be it's full name?

`Namespace.BaseClass.NestedClass` or `Namespace.Derived.NestedClass`? It wouldn't make sense for different names refer to the same class either.

For this same reason, you can't have it in different namespaces.

A possible solution would be to create an interface:

```
interface INested { }
```

And make your BaseClass generic:

```
class BaseClass<T> where T : INested, new()
{
   public T Nested { get; set; }
   public BaseClass()
   {
       Nested = new T();
   }
}

class Derived : BaseClass<NestedImpl>
{
   Derived()
   {
       Nested = new NestedImpl();
   }

   public class NestedImpl : INested
   {
       public int deeper {get;set;}
   }
}
```

Comment: I figured out I have an issue here, yet isn't there an OOP solution to expand a nested class in derived class ?

Comment: There is more than one good solution, depending on the case. You can, for example, make an interface `INestedClass`, and your `BaseClass<T> where T : INestedClass`

Comment: @Dani - why not derive the nested class, too? Or do you *have* to have that functionality in the base nested class? Why not implement it there in the first place?

Comment: @Corak deriving nested class would imply a cast to access deep property.

Comment: @Andre - Yes. My point is, if that functionality needs to be in the base nested class, then why not implement it there?

Comment: @Corak I may be wrong here, but it seemed to me that OP was trying to achieve specialization, and hoping the partial class would only be applied when the instance would be of type derived. Again, I may be wrong, and if I am, you're right to make it all part of the same definition.